# colorbox js - activity monitor not displaying during image load

Tags: jquery, colorbox

The activity indicator is not displaying when Colorbox js loads a new image. This worked fine in the past. Anyone else have this issue? Can't figure out what is causing problem. My code is straight from Jack Moore's site, (v1.3.20.1)

Activity monitor should display "loading.gif" until next image is loaded. It does work when I view ColorBox demos.

What would be turning off this display?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your file path, and post a demo online.  Like you said, if it works on my site and not on yours, then it's going to be difficult for anyone to answer your question because the problem is specific to your deployment.

Comment: Found the issue. The vendor using the code, ZenPhoto, had altered the CSS for example1 theme. I downloaded your CSS and it works fine.